# How to use rand() to generate numbers in a range?

Tags: c, random, max, min

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate Random numbers uniformly over entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)
>   [How to use rand function to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270382/how-to-use-rand-function-to)

Could anyone tell me how to use the rand() function in C programming with 1 = min and
7 = max, 1 and 7 included.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628

Answer (score 16):

This will do what you want:

```
rand() % 7 + 1
```

Explanation:

- `rand()` returns a random number between `0` and a large number.
- `% 7` gets the remainder after dividing by `7`, which will be an integer from `0` to `6` inclusive.
- `+ 1` changes the range to `1` to `7` inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator. It returns the remainder when dividing. Generate a number in range 0 to 6 by using 
`rand() % 7`. Add 1 to that to generate a number in range 1 to 7.