# How do you generate a random 12-digit number?

Tags: c++, random

I am writing a Bittorrent Client in C++ and need to generate a 20 Byte Peer ID. The first 8 characters are comprised of `-WW1000-` which represent the name of the client and the version number. The other 12 digits need to be a random number that need to be generated randomly every time the client starts.

How could I generate the 12 digit random number and concatenate it with a `std::string` containing the first 8 characters (`-WW1000-`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const string CurrentClientID = "-WW1000-";  
ostringstream os;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
{
    int digit = rand() % 10;
    os << digit;
}
string result = CurrentClientID + os.str();
```

Comment: This will work, as long as you don't need uniform distribution.

Comment: Also if two clients connect within the same period time(0) reports the same number both clients will get the same "Random" ID. Move the `srand` code outside of the function call.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to make a large string using `rand()` N times, where N is the length of the number in digits you want ([a naive way to avoid modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270382/how-to-use-rand-function-to)):

```
size_t length = 20;
std::ostringstream o;

o << "-WW1000-";
for (size_t ii = 8; ii < length; ++ii)
{
    o << rand(); // each time you'll get at least 1 digit
}

std::string id = o.str().substr(0, length);
```

And if you've got a new enough C++ compiler/library:

```
// #include <random>
std::random_device r;
std::mt19937 gen(r());
std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> idgen(0LL, 999999999999LL);

std::ostringstream o;
o << "-WW1000-";
o.fill('0');    
o.width(12);
o << idgen(gen);

std::string id = o.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how "secure" your id has to be, but because you said:

`that need to be generated randomly every time the client starts`,

you could probably just use that information (10 digits from seconds after 1970-01-01) and add another two random digits (00..99):

```
using namespace std;
...
...
ostringstream id;
id << "-WW1000-" << setw(10) << setfill('0') << time(0) << setw(2) << rand()%100;
...
```

On my system, this will, in this moment, print:

```
cout << id.str() << endl;

    -WW1000-134306070741
```

If your requirements are stronger, you should, of course, use a full-random based variant.